# Allowing user to sign in with two google account in flutter

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, gmail

How can I request users access to **two google account simultaneously** in flutter?
I have been looking solution for a long time but could not find any. There are few answers available on the internet which suggest using two different projects. But, I doubt that this solution is practical as we need google verification while publishing the app.

And to extend this question a bit further, can we do the same for outlook?

For those who did not get the question
The way Salesforce has both personal and team inbox, how can I implement the same in flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe we lack package to solve this problem.

Here is a resource that can be helpful.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app

To keep listening to local web server, you can create HTTPServer